# Status code 400 or 200 for error on another micro-service

Tags: http

My application is currently composed of two micro-services :

- A. Subscription micro-service
- B. Payment micro-service

It also uses another external service:

- C. Payment provider

If a user tries to create a subscription with an invalid card number (let's say his card is blocked) the C. service will return me a 200 with a "success" parameter to "false" (I don't handle this service so I can't do anything about that).

Now my question is, what status code should the Payment (B) and Subscription (A) micro-services return ?

I'm not sure if it's a 4** or a 200 (with a success parameter) because the request itself is ok, the input format is ok (even if the data inside it is invalid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation, a 200 clearly isn't correct, because the request wasn't successful.

My recommendation in such cases is HTTP 422 Unprocessable Entity, which is defined in WebDAV but widely understood, and indicates that the request was syntactically valid but had semantic errors that prevented successful processing.

Answer (score 1):

If the request is syntactically correct - e.g. card number matches some given regex, but is invalid in an another way it definitely should not be `400 Bad Request`. This is simply not a bad request.

It also should no return any of `2XX` codes since this codes are dedicated for successful responses and - as you set in body `success = false` is not a request that was processed successfully.

The code that will be the most appropriate will be `409 Conflict` along with clear message describing the problem. It indicates that request failed, clarifies why and states explicitly that after correcting the request it can be resubmitted.

Comment: I think this is best answer and http status `Conflict` is suitable for these cases.